# Value Error:need more than 1 value to unpack(Django)

Tags: python, django, forms

I have looked at similar problems but couldn't find any solutions.MY problem is when i click signup button,the information is saved and it is visible in django administration.But when i hit the signup button in the redirected url I get this error.
My forms.py is

```
from django import forms
from .models import SignUp
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
   full_name=forms.CharField()
   email=forms.EmailField()
   message=forms.CharField()

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model=SignUp
      fields=['full_name','email']
   def clean_email(self):
      email=self.cleaned_data.get("email")
      mail_base,provider=email.split("@")
      domain,extension=provider.split(".")
      if not extension=="edu":
         raise forms.ValidationError("Plase enter valid email address")
      return email
```

and my views.py is

```
from django.conf import settings
from django import forms
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm,SignUpForm

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
   title="welcome"
   form=SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
   context={
      "title":title,
      "form":form
   }
   if form.is_valid():
      instance=form.save(commit=False)
      full_name=form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")
      if not full_name:
         full_name="new"
      instance.full_name=full_name
      instance.save()
      context={
       "title":"Thank you"
       }



    return render(request,"home.html",context)


def contact(request):
  form=ContactForm(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
    email=form.cleaned_data.get("email")
    message=form.cleaned_data.get("message")
    full_name=form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")
  context={
    "form":form,
   }
  return render(request,"forms.html",context)
```

and models.py is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class SignUp(models.Model):
   email=models.EmailField(blank=True)
   full_name=models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=False)
   timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
   updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)

   def __unicode__(self):
     return self.email
```

and i get the error at "mail_base,provider=email.split("@")" in forms.py.Please help me..

Comment: What's the value of `email` when you split it?

Comment: @JCVanHamme normal emails like gmail...

Comment: Show `SignUp` model, please.

Comment: @VladimirDanilov I have added

Comment: Try print `email` variable in your form `clean_email`, it might be `None` or doesn't have `@` in it.

Comment: What is the error? Could you provide full traceback?

Comment: It doesnt look like you are doing much in the clean method except checking for the extension - why not just do `email=self.cleaned_data.get("email", "")` and then `if not email.endswith(".edu"): raise ValidationError` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone leaves `email` field blank (this is allowed because of SignUp model `email = EmailField(blank=True)`), then `self.cleaned_data.get('email')` will return `''` (empty string). `mail_base, provider = email.split('@')` will raise that exception in this case.

Comment: @abhaygurrala take a look at karthikr comment to your post also.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this would happen is that your `email` string, for some reason, did not have an '@' symbol in it.  This leads `email.split("@")` to result in a list of length 1, rather than a list of length 2, as you were expecting.

My guess is that you have a blank email somewhere, but any `email` field that doesn't have an '@' symbol will cause this exception to be raised.